# minted and tabs

Tags: minted

I can get a code block including tab characters in a `minted` environment to work with the `obeytabs` option, which results in a tab size of 8. The `tabsize` option, however, will mess up the tab alignment.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{pastie}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[obeytabs,showtabs]{c}
    int foo     //bar
            //ffff
\end{minted}
\begin{minted}[tabsize=4,showtabs]{c}
    int foo     //bar
                //ffff
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

The output looks as follows:

[image: output]

Is there a solution to this?

Comment: What would help is a picture or at least a description of the expected output.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I am possibly missing the point because I've set up my editor to automatically expand tabs, but after disabling this (I think) it seems to me that `minted` does do what it is supposed to here. The problem is that in your second example you have forgotten to include the `obeytabs` option. If you put this in then minted does what (I think) you want.

For example, I get what seems to me to be the following perfectly reasonable output

[image]

from the following latex file:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{pastie}
\begin{document}

\begin{minted}[tabsize=2,obeytabs,showtabs]{c}
    int foo //bar
            //ffff
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[tabsize=4,obeytabs,showtabs]{c}
    int foo //bar
            //ffff
\end{minted}

\begin{minted}[tabsize=6,obeytabs,showtabs]{c}
    int foo //bar
            //ffff
\end{minted}

\end{document}
```

If I've misunderstood the issue let me know and I'll delete this.

*(Btw, I could have answered this in the comments but I'm trying to start a movement to stop answering questions in the comments because currently there are **4190** questions posted on TeX.SX with no answers...except that I suspect that most of these questions are actually answered in the comments!)*

Comment: Perhaps worth noting that this is a `fancyvrb` thing: you don't need `minted` to see the effect.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. I was confused by the minted documentation which states **tabsize (integer) (default: 8) The number of spaces a tab is equivalent to if obeytabs is not active.**